# Need to organize words based on their components, any other way aside from brute force?

Tags: java, algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm not sure if this process has a name.

I have some words (about 9,000). They are in Japanese, but I'll try to explain this using English words. I want to categorize the words by the components (in English, letters).

A

B

C

act bar play

This should create:

A: play

B: bar

C: act

Now, 'a' appears in all 3 words, but I want to make sure that each category (letter) has at least word. Now, it would make sense to delete a word after it's used, but there are a few cases where 2 letters make up one word and that's each letter's only word--so I'd like to account for that somehow.

Is there an approach for solving this aside from brute force? Dynamic programming perhaps? Even a name for this process (if it exists) would be great.

Comment: How would you categorize "back" which has all 3 letters? This sounds like more of a grouping problem -- maybe a machine learning classifier like k nearest neighbor? The trick is "which one of the matching categories should this item go in" (?)

Comment: @RobY If all categories have equal amount of words, it can randomly go into either one. Otherwise, it should go into the category with the fewest words. I'd like the categories to be fairly even, at least as much as possible. Seems like I would need a lot of backtracking.

Comment: Since you don't know the distribution (i.e. count) of all items in all possible categories, you could rely on luck and just hope they come in evenly. However, if the goal is to even out the distribution, then you might have to put all words in every category that fits, that *then* start the distribution process of putting each word into its "final" category. That way you'd be working with full knowledge of the distributions. I haven't thought through how that might play out, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) is a powerful library used to do a variety of text searching and stemming and it might be worth taking a look at. The typical use case is full-text search but it is pretty component based under the hood so you could certainly build a custom analyizer or stemmer to get to where you wanted to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this as a maximum flow problem.  A maximum flow problem optimizes a flow in a network.  It can be used to solve assignment problems.  You want to assign words to categories.

You need to build a graph as follows:

Each category and each word is a node, to which you have to add a start node and an end node.

From the start node, add an edge going to each category.
From each category add an edge going to each word that is compatible with the category.
From each word, add an edge going to the end node.
All edges have capacity 1.

In this graph you want to maximuze the flow going from the start node to the end node.  The Ford-Fulkerson is especially interesting because it works with integer weights and returns a solution in integers.

The solution assigns one word to each category just follow for each category which edge has a positive flow.  If it is impossible to assign a word to all categories, it will return the assignment that maximizes the number of categories matched with a word.

If you have more words than categories, or any words left over, you can assign the remaining words to the first matching category.

This will guarantee that a maximum of categories have at least one word matched.

Comment: This sounds similar to what I want. Is there any way to repeat the process so there are no words left over but distribute them as evenly as possible?

Comment: I can't think of a way to find an optimal assignment.  If you don't mind doing a few iterations, you could set the capacity on the edges from the start node to the category to be some fixed value N.  This will return an assignment of maximum N words to each category.  If you want to minimize the maximum of words per category, you can find that by trying different values of N.